# Drop Down List Changer

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

How do I make a selector drop down list? When selected I'd like it to choose the css for an item.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: You'll have to provide some more information. At the very least show us the mark-up of your `select` element (and, ideally, its parent `form` element). If you could explain what you want to happen when an `option` from the `select` is selected that would also help. Could you provide a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)? And, just as importantly, what do you mean by "when selected it will chose the css for the selected item"?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chrismhodges/GmjAL/

Comment: Also, the select option, I would like to select a css for each different item, do you understand what i mean?>

Comment: Your JS Fiddle shows *two* `select` elements. If I choose (from 'event') 'Yellow Truck-Pickups' and (from 'driver') 'Tommy' what should happen? How do these choices relate to 'css'?

Comment: Well the Driver, is just a basic input, but for yellow truck selector would need to pick the css designated to it.

Comment: What CSS is that? Where is it?

Comment: .white_truck,
44 .fc-agenda .white_truck .fc-event-time,
45 .white_truck a {
46 background-color: #737373; /* background color */
47 border-color: #333333; /* border color */
48 color: white; /* text color */
49 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really isn't all that difficult.  The example below would change text on an item with id=itemtochange to be red if value 1 was selected, else it would change to blue.  There are a million different variations to this, but you get the picture.

Your select box:

```
<select id="selectbox">
  <option value="value1">Val 1</option>
  <option value="value2">Val 2</option>
 </select>
```

And the Jquery:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#selectbox').change(function() {
      if $('#selectbox').val() == 'value1' {
        $('#itemtochange').css("color","red");
      } else {
        $('#itemtochange').css("color","blue");
      }
   });
 </script>`
```

Comment: Would, this interact with arshaws fullcalendar?  I have it fully set up and implemented minus the database and a few bugs.

Comment: @chris, the Dom is the Dom regardless of what's interacting with it.  As with all things jQuery, identify the element you want to tweak, find the correct selector, and tweak away.  If you're looking to get specific code written, we can discuss my consulting rate....

Comment: Also do you have to use else, what if you have about 10 different selections?

Comment: No, I do thank you for the help Mr. Peterson, but I was just looking for basic help, I am rather good at fixing once I find the right path.

Comment: i think I fixed it, I just juse a comma, after ("color","red), 

if $('#selectbox').val() == 'value2' {
        $('#itemtochange').css("color","blue");

i think that is correct